# Ride.py shows Calling method 'start_keyword' of listener XXX failed

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to run an automated test in `Ride.py`. This test works on my colleague's computer but for some reason does not work on mine. The test starts but at a certain point i get the following error:

```py
[ ERROR ] Calling method 'start_keyword' of listener 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\contrib\testrunner\TestRunnerAgent.py' failed: IndexError: list index out of range
```

The interesting part is that this error occurs on the same spot ever time, but with a different test it happens at a different time.

I tried to google several things and nothing worked. One solution suggested there was a `'#'` commented somewhere and this caused the crash. I looked but I don't see a `'#'` commented anywhere.

Another suggestion lead me to believe my `testrunneragent.py` file must have been installed wrong. I went online to find the file and replaced it. This did not work either (reran the test before and after a restart of ride)

We tried to re-import the test files thinking perhaps something went wrong there. This did not help either.

Googling juts the last part (`IndexError: list index out of range`) gave me the suggestion it does not recognize all the lines of code in the back-end file. I would have no clue how to solve this as im not a major coder.

One difference between me and my colleague could be the versions. I downloaded python version 2.7.16 and ride 1.7.3.1. My colleague uses an older version of both python and RIDE. Perhaps the problem could be here?

https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/TLekH3az0m4wuUyM8C2RYw

I expect the test will run without failing (it is a happy flow) I have included some screenshots with code in the previous segment that might help

Comment: I recommend to re-install RIDE. I would also look at the test file for being encoded UTF-8. Are the versions of `robot` exactly the same?

Answer (score 0):

downgraded to the same version of Ride.py
This seems to have fixed the issue